# load new viewcontroller in method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Im new in objective c.
I have this method, and i want it to load a new view, in the end, from my storyboard. How can i do that?

```
- (void)stopAnimatingAndLoadView {
    [self.indicator stopAnimating];

    // load new view
}
```

Hope you understand my question

Answer (score 0):

The new view that you want to load, I assume, is a UIViewController and you have already set it up in storyboard. In storyboard, if you give it an identifier, then you can load it by calling:

> ```
> MyOtherViewController *myOtherViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyOtherViewController"];
> // If you are using navigation controller, you can call
> [self.navigationController pushViewController:myOtherViewController animated:YES];
>
> // If not, you can present it modally
> [self presentModalViewController:myOtherViewController animated:YES];
> ```